# Rules of quenching across phase transition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, atomic-physics, phase-transition

Consider a Hamiltonian undergoing phase transition

$$H(g) = H_{0} + g H_{1}$$

when $g>g_{c}$.  Let us consider an initial state which is the ground state of Hamiltonian with $g<g_{c}$ is suddenly quenched across phase transition by a Hamiltonian with $H(g_{f} = g>g_{c})$.

After quenching, the state goes to a complicated state which can be written as a superposition of states of the basis states of $H(g_{f}= g>g_{c})$.

$$\vert \psi_{f} \rangle = \sum_{i} C_{n} \vert \phi_{n}(g_{f})\rangle$$

The above expression says that there is a finite probability that the system can be any one of the eigenstates of $H(g_{f}= g>g_{c})$. My question is suppose a quantum system is transitioning from one state to other state, physically there are rules that allow or forbid certain transitions.  For example, In hydrogen atom problem, there are transition rules which forbids certain transitions inside the atom. Are there such transition rules exists in quenching a state from ground state of a Hamiltonian from one phase to another phase? If yes, what are they, give me specific example if possible.

Comment: Can you provide a reference where this notion of quenching is used?

Comment: @Quillo, reference for sudden quenching?

Comment: The one that you believe is "as close as possible" to your question. Where did you take this idea? Where does this question come from? :)

Comment: @Quillo I was just wondering, there should be some rules right? My question is not based on any paper

Comment: This is the problem: there are rules if there is a clear procedure for your "phase transition". The process may, or may not, conserve some quantities and, therefore, provide selection rules.. or not! This is why I am asking about the procedure/references.